# How to call get_current_user_id() in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to update user profile fields for logged in user, for example:

```
 $userid = get_current_user_id();
update_user_meta( $userid, $key, $value );
// this code inside of plugin
```

But it don't work.

I read that we need  use get_current_user_id(); under init action.But how this look in this case? Or problen in another?

Comment: what error(s) are you seeing?

Comment: Thank for your question, Dan! If I put the id of user  like number for exapmle update_user_meta( 35, $key, $value ); it's work in case above it's doesn't work.

Comment: $userid==0, even  if user logged in

Comment: Are you calling get_current_user_id(); in the correct file? By correct file I mean if your plugin name is "my-plugin" then all the inbuilt functions will work properly in "my-plugin.php"

Comment: Hi  Santosh! I put all code in  correct file, but it don't solve problem. What else I can do?)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
    function yourfunction(){
$a=get_current_user_id();
        update_user_meta( $a, 'field', 'test');
}
add_action('init', 'yourfunction');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code in the init action but the most important conditional check is to use this function is_user_logged_in() which determines whether someone is logged in or not. So wrap your code inside this check it will work.